# How to update a many to many field in Django using the Signals

Tags: python, django, django-signals

I have two models:

```
class Website(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField()
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.url)



class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user.username)
```

This is the signal I've tried to complete:

```
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Website.users.through)
def update_bio_when_websites_updated(sender, instance, action, reverse, **kwargs):
    pass
```

I need to create a signal to update the **bio** of the user when It's websites modified or updated.

But I don't have any idea.
How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Following might be solution but not used signals, instead override the save method in
Website Model.

```
class Website(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField()
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.url)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk: # work only for updates
            for user in self.users.all():# it may slow down if no of users is high.
             user.bio  = 'some thing'
             user.save()
    super().save(*args, **kwargs) # calling the save
```

> Note: If there the number of users attached to a website is too high,
> iterating over all users attached to the website slow downs the
> application, then updating the bio of user can be do as a background
> task.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that like this.

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, m2m_changed
from django.dispatch import receiver

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Profile, Website


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Website.users.through)
def update_bio_when_websites_updated(sender, instance, action, reverse, **kwargs):
    if action == 'post_add':
        if reverse:
            instance.profile.bio = '\n'.join(list(map(lambda x: x.url, instance.website_set.all().order_by('url'))))
            instance.profile.save()
        else:
            for user in instance.users.all():
                user.profile.bio = '\n'.join(list(map(lambda x: x.url, user.website_set.all().order_by('url'))))
                user.profile.save()
```

Also, There is another way that you can give it a try.You can print inputs of the `update_bio_when_websites_updated` into the body and see what action is needed to be taken like this.

```
def update_bio_when_websites_updated(sender, instance, action, reverse, pk_set, **kwargs):
    if action == 'post_add':
        # Add user to website - instance: website
        if not reverse:
               print(instance)
               print(pk_set)
        # Add website to user - instance: user
        else:
               print(instance)
               print(pk_set)
```

By running this you will get to know what to do.